# How should one handle NSURLAuthenticationMethodXMobileMeAuthToken?

Tags: cocoa, icloud, nsurlsession

We're using a `NSURLSessionDataDelegate` and have the following delegate method implemented:

```
- (void) URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler { ... }
```

Frequently we find that users of iCloud receive a `NSURLAuthenticationMethodXMobileMeAuthToken` challenge. Sending back a rejection doesn't work (as the server won't try another challenge) and sending back an acceptance with

`completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, credential);`

doesn't work either.

What are we supposed to do with this authentication challenge type? Has anyone else seen it?

Comment: What's the protectionSpace associated with these calls look like?

Comment: Have you tried calling the completion handler with NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling and nil for credential?

Comment: How about with NSURLSessionAuthChallengeRejectProtectionSpace and nil for the credential? If so, does your delegate should get called again with the next authentication projection space?

Answer (score 1):

For any protection space that you aren't explicitly handling, or for any credential type that you don't understand, you should typically use `NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling` (the credential is ignored, but typically pass `nil`) to tell the OS to handle the credential as though you didn't provide an authentication delegate method.

Comment: The trouble is - I've tried every combination of this and anything else, but it won't go away. Just recently though, I think I know what this might be. Essentially the "authorisation" header may have been missing from the request due to a re-direct, and so when that isn't there, iCloud sends a MobileMe token auth challenge and nothing else. Intercepting re-directs and then adding an authorisation header back in again seems to have 'fixed' this.

Comment: What servers are you hitting?

Comment: cadav.icloud.com

Comment: Ah.  Now that makes sense.  I assume you're manually injecting an auth header during the initial request?  Then yes, the right solution is to also alter the `NSURLRequest` whenever you get a redirect, to ensure that the auth header is also included in those.